# Detail about in a proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Proposition:
[image]
proof:[image]
note:[image]

I don't figure it out.

I'll use *u'* and *v'* instead of [image: *f* o *u*] and [image: *f* o *v*].

$u' \circ v'= u' ( v' ( f ) ) = u' ( f( v ) ) = f ( u ( v ) ) =f \circ u \circ v $

Something seems wrong.
Can someone help me fix my equation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both you and the book are wrong.

You can figure out the proper order just by looking at domains. We have:

$u:M' -> M$

$v: M -> M''$

$f:M'' -> N$

So the only composition that makes sense is $f \circ v \circ u$.

In terms of the morphisms $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{v}$, we have:

$\bar{u} \circ \bar{v}(f) = \bar{u}(\bar{v}(f)) = \bar{u}(f \circ v) = (f \circ v) \circ u$

Your mistake was writing $u'(f(v)) = f(u(v))$. It's maybe easiest to see this if we put in the argument of the function: $u'(f(v))(m') = f(v(u(m')))$. So $u'(f(v)) = f(v(u))$.